# How to implement API search onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

My project is using React, Axios, and movieDB's API. I am trying to make it so that when I type out a movie title and either hit enter and/or click submit then the API will return the title of the movie searched for as an h1 element.

currently, the code works as soon as I refresh the browser and the only way for it to function properly is if I go into the code and replace `${query}` with what I want to search for, ie `joker`. I have tried adding the onclick to the button : `<button onclick="componentDidMount()">submit</button>`. This did not do anything, however.

App.js

```
import React from "react"
import Movielist from './components/Movielist'



function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="search" />
            <button onclick="componentDidMount()">submit</button>
            <h1 id="title">title</h1>
            <Movielist />
        </div>

    )
}

export default App
```

Movielist.js

```
import React from 'react';

import axios from 'axios';

export default class Movielist extends React.Component {
  state = {
    title: ""
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const API_KEY = '*****************';
    const query = document.getElementById('search');
    axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&query=${query}`)
      .then(res => {
        const title = res.data['results'][0]['title'];
        this.setState({ title });

      })
  }

  render() {
    return (

    <h1>{this.state.title}</h1>

    )
  }
}
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few things wrong here:

- The structure of your app is not great, eg. seperate out your API calls
- You are calling a lifecycle method, these are called automatically
- Don't use DOM selectors like getElementById in React
- Use camelcase event listeners (onclick should be onClick)
- Use callbacks with event listeners or they will fire immediatly
- You included your API key on stackoverflow, big mistake!

**Try this:**
https://codepen.io/alexplummer/pen/YzwyJOW

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

const MovielistSearch = props => (
    <>
        <input type="search" onChange={e => props.saveSearchInput(e.target.value)} />
        <button type="button" onClick={() => props.handleSearch()}>
            Search
        </button>
    </>
);

const getMovies = props => {
  return ['Title 1', 'Title 2', 'Title 3'];
  // ADD REAL API HERE
  // const API_KEY = '';
  // const getMovies = await axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&query=${props.searchTerm}`);
  // return getMovies.data;
}

const MovieList = props => (
    <ul>
        {props.foundMovies.map(thisMovie=><li>{thisMovie}</li>)}
    </ul>
);

const App = () => {
  const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState("");
  const [foundMovies, setFoundMovies] = useState([]);

  const movieSearch = ()=> {
    if (searchInput == null) return;
    const foundMovies = getMovies(searchInput);
    setFoundMovies(foundMovies);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 id="title">Movie list</h1>
      <MovielistSearch saveSearchInput={setSearchInput} handleSearch={movieSearch} />
      <MovieList foundMovies={foundMovies} />
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Comment: where do I put that?

Comment: Just add the ()=> before ComponentDidMount()

Comment: I tried adding that to the button in App.js and ```componentDidMount()``` in Movielist.js. Is there a way you can respond with the edited code as I am not quite sure what you mean.

Answer (score -1):

The problem might be here:

```
const query = document.getElementById('search');
```

It returns an HTML element. Try document.getElementById('search').innerText

Comment: That returns this error ```TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null```

Comment: Try adding an ID to the input element:
<input type="search" id="search" />

Comment: No longer returns an error but when I click submit nothing happens

Comment: You need the get the value of the input and store it in the query variable.

<input type="search" id="search" />

const query= document.getElementById('search').value;

I would suggest to console.log() the query so you will know exactly what is its value.

Comment: Don't use DOM selectors in React